# Google's Volley Library in MVC Framework

Tags: java, android, model-view-controller, android-volley

Please could someone supply me with an example of Google's Volley Library that is used in an MVC framework design?

I would like the Volley Networking to be in the model and be used in the Controller to display it on the View (As MVC should be)

Im struggling to see how it can be used?

My issue is getting the response out of say Networking.java and use the JSON Response in a controller class that will spew out the required response for a specific view?

I just to be pointed in the right direction as to where Volley has been used in an MVC Framework so I can see how they structured their code?

Comment: use Gson and VolleyGsonRequest : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html to get your response as a model